# Characterization of Normal RVs by uni variate version?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

If $X$ is a symmetric $n$-dimensional random vector with mean $0$ then is it true that:
\begin{align*}
& X \text{ follows a multivariate normal law} \\
& \text{iff} \\
& \|X\| \text{is a chi random variable with $n$ degrees of freedom?}
\end{align*}

One implication is direct but is the converse true?  That is does $\|X\|\sim\chi$ imply $X$ is normal?

---

**Explanation of Symmetric**
A random variable is said to be symmetric iff:
For each $i,j\in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ $X_i=X_j$.
In other words: $X=\sum_{i=1}^n X_1e_i$, where $e_i$ are the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: How about $X = (R, \Theta)$ (polar coordinates) where $R \sim \chi$, but $\Theta = u \in \mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ a.s. ?

Comment: The dimensions don't work...

Comment: You can decompose the distribution of $X$ into a radial part and an angular part. The distribution of $\| X \|$ will only see the radial part, so you can pick any angular part you want. It doesn't have to be uniformly distributed (as it would be if $X$ were $N(0,\sigma^2 I_n)$).

Comment: If you actually have $X=\sum_i X_1 e_i$, then Cov($X_i,X_j$) is identically equal to Var($X_1$), so strictly speaking your converse holds, but actually a *lot* more holds, because the covariance matrices that you can have are *extremely* constrained.

Comment: @Ian does spherical symmetry not imply uniform $\theta$

Comment: @snarfblaat CSA said what "symmetric" means in this context. It is not spherical symmetry.

Comment: QUOTE A random variable is said to be symmetric iff:
For each $i,j\in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ $X_i=X_j$. END QUOTE.  If that's really what you meant, then the answer is definitely "no".  If you mean the _distribution_ of $X_i$ is equal to the _distribution_ of $X_j$, that's a different matter.  And the answer is still "no" there. $\qquad$

Comment: Nobody calls this condition being symmetric. The OP should check thoroughly their definition of a symmetric distribution.

Comment: By the way, with this definition of symmetric, the implication the post says is "direct" is actually wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the current edition of the question:

> If $X$ is a symmetric $n$-dimensional random vector with mean $0$ then is it true that:
>   \begin{align*}
> & X \text{ follows a multivariate normal law} \\
> & \text{iff} \\
> & \|X\| \text{is a chi random variable with $n$ degrees of freedom?}
> \end{align*}

Let $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$. As phrased above, the question ignores all questions of the correlations between $X_i$, $X_j$ and the variances.

Suppose, for example, that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are **independent** (which doesn't follow from the assumptions above) and normally distributed with mean $0$ and respective standard deviations $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n$.  Then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{X_i^2}{\sigma_i^2} \sim \chi^2_n,
$$
but the same is not true of $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$.

Next, suppose $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ are independent, are normally distributed, have expectation $0$, and have variance $1$, and let
$$
X_i = Y_i - \overline Y, \quad \text{where } \overline Y = \frac{Y_1+\cdots+Y_n} n.
$$
Then one can show that $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ has a multivariate normal distribution, that each $X_i$ has expected value $0$, that they all have the same standard deviation, and even that all pairs $(X_i,X_j)$ (for $i\ne j$) have the same distribution (and are negatively correlated), and that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \sim \chi^2_{n-1}.
$$

Comment: +1. Valiant effort to transform the question into something useful.